# Slow bash script using grep and sed

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to speed up my script, which currently takes approx 30 seconds. I am a novice to bash, and I am sure I am using some bad scripting practice (found some hint in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765 but still cannot fix my issue).

What I need to do is get data from an external file, and extract numbers into two arrays. My script works fine, except it is too slow.

```
readData=`cat $myfile` 
# readData = [[1491476100000,60204],[1491476130000,59734],...,[1491476160000,60150]]
# I have approximately 5000 points (two numbers in each point)
pointTime=()
pointVal=()

for line in `echo $readData | grep -Po "[0-9]+,[0-9]+"`; do  
  # Get first number but drop last three zeroes (e.g. 1491476100)
  pointTime+=(`echo $line | grep -Po "^[0-9]+" | sed "s/\(.*\)000$/\1/"`)   
  # Get second number, e.g. 60204
  pointVal+=(`echo $line | grep -Po "[0-9]+$"`)
done
```

Maybe I could use some regex inside a parameter expansion, but I don't know how.

Comment: If you could show us sample Input_file and expected output, we could help more on same then

Comment: You can already find what you're asking as comments in the above code

Comment: What are you going to do with the data once you have it loaded into the arrays?  It is not at all clear that Bash is going to be a great choice to process this data.  For example, notice that your input file is valid JSON. Most any language would have a simple way to to load this into a native data structure, or you could even directly manipulate it in javascript.

Comment: It is a small part of multiple processing steps. Once a day I grab data from website with cURL, then I process it (split, divide, filter, add offset, sampling, etc.), then I save part of the data into a MySQL database. I am not sure I could have used a different language, but now it's complete so I am not planning to reconsider. I thought that mentioning only the relevant part was helpful for analyzing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fast Alternative

Here's how I would write the script:

```
mapfile -t points < <(grep -Po '\d+,\d+' "$myfile")
pointTime=("${points[@]%000,*}")
pointVal=("${points[@]#*,}")
```

or even

```
mapfile -t pointTime < <(grep -Po '\d+(?=000,)' "$myfile")
mapfile -t pointVal < <(grep -Po ',\K\d+' "$myfile")
```

when you are sure that the file is well-formed.

## Problems of the old Script

You already identified the main problem: The loop is slow, especially, since a lot of programs are called inside the loop. Nevertheless here are some hints how you could have improved your script without throwing away the loop. Some parts were needlessly complicated, for instance

```
readData=`cat $myfile` 
`echo $readData | grep -Po "[0-9]+,[0-9]+"`
```

can be written as

```
grep -Po "[0-9]+,[0-9]+" "$myfile"
```

and

```
echo $line | grep -Po "^[0-9]+" | sed "s/\(.*\)000$/\1/"
```

can be written as

```
grep -Po "^[0-9]+(?=000)" <<< "$line"
```

A big speed boost would be to use bash's matching operator `=~` instead of `grep`, because just starting up `grep` is slow.

```
[[ "$line" =~ (.*)000,(.*) ]]
pointTime+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
pointTime+=("${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")
```

Comment: This is the fully explanatory and useful. You edited several times, the solution I implemented is `points=($(grep -Po '[0-9]+,[0-9]+' <<< "$readData")) ; 
pointTime=("${points[@]%000,*}") ; 
pointVal=("${points[@]#*,}")`. I didn't use $myfile since my actual code is more complex. With your solution the code is extremely quick, no slowdown at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm suspicious of the requirement to store the results in an array.  You probably actually want to loop over the values in pairs.  In any event, storing intermediate values in memory is inelegant and wasteful.

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+,[0-9]+' "$myfile" |
while IFS=, read -r first second, do
    process value pair "${first%000}" "$second"
done
```

If you insist on storing the values in an array, how to change the body of the loop should be obvious.

```
    pointTime+=("${first%000}")
    pointVal+=("$second")
```

Comment: I need to store all the data for further processing, see my comment to original question. Even if I accepted Socowi's answer, your solution looks really good, too. +1